# JAVA. Running a function from different class

Tags: java

I am new on Java and I need a small help.

Why when I run a function from another class it doesn't work(obj.setTime()):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    apple obj= new apple();
    System.out.println(obj.TheTime());
    obj.setTime();
    System.out.println(obj.TheTime());
}}
```

it also doesn't work if I put `obj.setTime(h,m,s);` or `obj.setTime(int h, int m, int s);`
but if I put `obj.setTime(1,2,3);` it works. I am addint setTime() function.

```
public void setTime(int h, int m, int s) {
    Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in); 
    h=reader.nextInt();
    m=reader.nextInt();
    s=reader.nextInt();
    hour= ((h>=0 && h<24) ? h: 0);
    minute= ((m>=0 && m<60) ? m: 0);
    second= ((s>=0 && s<60) ? s : 0);   
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: This is an example of a (very) simple question, but it's not inherently a bad one. Granted it could be clearer, but I think it's easy enough to figure out the OP has a problem with the syntax used to call methods. I don't think it deserves to necessarily be downvoted and closed for that reason.

Comment: You need to provide three arguments or three expressions. You can't use variables  you haven't defined in the local scope and you can't define new ones this way.

Comment: Note: the three values `(h, m, s)` you require are not used so you should just make them local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified three parameters to your `setTime()` method of type `int` in your method definition, so you need to specify three parameters of type `int` when you call your method.

So to take your non-working examples:

`obj.setTime();` - won't compile, as you're not providing any parameters.

`obj.setTime(h,m,s);` - won't compile, as you're providing it three variables that don't exist.

`obj.setTime(int h, int m, int s)` - won't compile, as you're confusing the definition of the function with calling it.

Your only working example (`obj.setTime(1,2,3);`) passes three integers - 1, 2 and 3 - hence it compiles.

Note though that your `setTime()` method doesn't actually *use* any of the parameter values passed in - it immediately overwrites them with values read from the console. So it may be that you want something like:

```
public void setTime() {
    Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in); 
    int h=reader.nextInt();
    int m=reader.nextInt();
    int s=reader.nextInt();
    hour= ((h>=0 && h<24) ? h: 0);
    minute= ((m>=0 && m<60) ? m: 0);
    second= ((s>=0 && s<60) ? s : 0);   
}
```

...which doesn't take *any* parameters (so you can just call `setTime()`), but instead defines the variables read from the console within the method body.